# Laravel Delete button not working with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a Laravel post application where I create and display posts. I am now trying to delete a post using an Ajax call. Let's say I have 10 posts displaying. When I click on the delete button of the first post, I get a `405 Method Not Allowed` error. When I click on the delete button on any of the posts below, absolutely nothing happens, no error or warning message. Please take note that my CSRF tokens are set up and working. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Here is the HTML:

```
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="postContainer" id="post{{ $post->id }}">
      <h4 class="postHeading" id="showtitle">{{ $post->title }}</h4>
      <p class="post" id="postBody">{{ $post->post }}</p>
      <span class="authorName" id="showauthor">{{ $post->author }}</span>
      <span class="postDate" id="showpostDate">{{ $post->created_at }}</span>
      <input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete" data-id="{{ $post->id }}">
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <div class="message" id="message">

    </div>
```

Here is my Ajax call:

```
    $("#delete").on("click", function(){

      var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
        }
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: '/index/delete/' + id,
        type: "POST",
        data: {_method: 'delete'},
        success:function(response){
          $("#message").append("<div>" + response.message + "</div>");
        },
      });

    });
```

Here is my Route:

```
   Route::post('/index/delete/{id}', 'HomeController@delete');
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function delete($id){
  Post::find($id)->delete();
  return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Id always unique...

Comment: set `type: "POST",` to `type: "GET",` and check

Comment: FYI better  to use the `.data('id')` instead of `.attr('data-id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this in your code

**id to class**

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" class="delete" value="Delete" data-id="{{ $post->id }}">
```

**in script**

call **class(.)** not **id(#)**

and **data('id')** not **attr('data-id')**

```
$(".delete").on("click", function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
```

Comment: Thank you, it is solved now. Only thing is - I don't understand why the class must be used instead of id? I used an Ajax call to insert data and I used the id and it worked 100%. Can you maybe explain, please? Thank you, again.

Comment: ID is identity of any object. That must be unique for every new object or element if you provide same ID to more then one element then that ID assign to the element appears first. The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id. [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

Comment: And yet my id "delete" was unique... Still don't understand why use class instead.

Comment: You are using this in `foreach` loop.. That make is repeat... for each iteration...

Comment: Oh I see! Now I understand. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have the reputation to comment so I'm posting this as an answer.
And yes you have to change your javascript because ID is unique and you can only give it to one input and call one input by it.
In your routes/web.php I would do 
`Route::post('/index/delete/{post}', 'HomeController@delete')->name('posts_delete');` name is optional for a named route but it often helps (with a named route you can do `{{ route('posts_delete') }}` for the url in your ajax but you have to add the id as data
So in your HomeController you can do

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
{
  $post->delete();
  return back();
}
```

Don't forget `use App\Post;`

Also I would recommend a PostController that handles Posts
`php artisan make:controller PostsController --resource` creates a Controller with methods like destroy